# small plot with no margins - border with line width (lwd) equal to 1 not visible

Tags: r, plot, border, margins

I've been trying to make some very tiny line graphs using base plotting functions, but am coming unstuck when trying to add a thin border.

This is via RGui on Windows 7, saving a png from the plot window.

Here's my code:

```
dev.new(width=1.3,height=0.3)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

set.seed(13)
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10)

plot(x,y,type="n",xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ylim=c(0,1))
polygon( c(1,x,max(x),0), c(0,y,0,0), col="lightblue", border=NA)
lines(x,y,lwd=1)
```

Everything is fine until I try to add a box with a line width of 1, giving:

```
box(lwd=1)
```

[image]

Now I can solve this by increasing the line width to 2, but this seems a bit of a hack.

```
box(lwd=2)
```

[image]

Using `rect` like `rect(1,0,10,1)`  doesn't seem to give me an appropriate solution either, with the bottom and right borders not being visible.

Comment: I suspect you have "stretched" that image, since its specification was a small "square">

Comment: @DWin - yep, RGui was forcing a larger width to fit in the window controls. I have adjusted the width to `1.3` which is about the same ratio as the above images. It doesn't affect the root issue however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question thanks to @baptiste's tip-off, this is a device dependent issue due to RGui. If the image is saved directly out to file using `png` everything works as intended. E.g.:

```
dev.new(width=1.3,height=0.3)
# repeat from here onwards only for png call below
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
set.seed(13)
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10)
plot(x,y,type="n",xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ylim=c(0,1),bty="n")
polygon( c(1,x,max(x),0), c(0,y,0,0), col="lightblue", border=NA)
lines(x,y,lwd=1)
box(lwd=1)
```

Saving out to png from the "R Graphics" window gives my original stuffed up image:

[image]

Going directly to file using `png` like:

```
png("textbox_direct.png",width=116,height=27)
# take code block from above
dev.off()
```

...gives the correct result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered giving mar a small non-zero value:

```
dev.new(width=0.3,height=0.3)
par(mar=c(0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01))

set.seed(13)
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10)

plot(x,y,type="n",xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ylim=c(0,1))
polygon( c(1,x,max(x),0), c(0,y,0,0), col="lightblue", border=NA)
lines(x,y,lwd=1)

box(lwd=1)
```

I admit I haven't quite figured out what the end-game might be, but when I do an interactive "stretch" of that very small screen-object, it does result in  an all-around border.

[image]

I do recognize that I am on a Mac and saving this to a pdf file and converting it to a png file for SO-inclusion may not be precisely reproducible on a Linux or Windows device.

Comment: Hmmh... that does seem to work with `lwd=1` to give the intended result on Win7/RGui. I'll wait and see if anyone else has any pearls of wisdom as to the reasoning behind this before I accept.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution base in `grid` and `gridBase` package. The idea is to replace the `box` by `grid.rect`.

1. Use `gridBase` to get the `base` viewport
2. Introduce some offset (viewport y ) to show the bottom line
3. Reduce the width of the viewport to show the right line.

Here my code:

```
library(gridBase)
sp <- baseViewports()
vp <- sp$plot
vp$width <- unit(0.999,'npc')
vp$y <- unit(0.001,'npc')
pushViewport(vp)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill=NA))
upViewport(1)
```

[image]

**EDIT** thanks to @baptiste, you can simply get the same result using only `grid.rect`:

```
library(grid)
grid.rect(width = unit(0.999,'npc'),
          y = unit(0.5001, "npc"),
          gp=gpar(fill=NA))
```

Comment: if the plot is using the full device window, why bother with gridBase? grid.rect() alone would work just as well, no? I can't reproduce the original issue, it might be device-dependent.

Comment: @baptiste you're right! Maybe I like too much manipulate `viewports`... or also influenced by the OP comment *"Using rect like rect(1,0,10,1) doesn't seem to give me an appropriate solution"*...

Comment: @baptiste - I hadn't considered device-specific issues. If I go straight to `png` everything is a-ok. If I try to save the image via RGui I get issues. Gah!